# How do you center a <g> within a <svg> in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I am trying to center a group that has a d3 tree inside of it. The svg is currently positioned perfectly across the browser and I am just trying to get the dynamically loaded tree to stay in the center of that svg element. All tree elements are within one group and have a zoom listener and have the ability to pan.

```
<svg width="1535" height="685" overflow-y="hidden" class="overlay">
    <g transform="translate(742.5,342.5)scale(1)">
        <g class="node" transform="translate(0,25)">
          <circle class="nodeCircle" r="4.5" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255)</circle>
          <text x="10" dy=".35em" class="nodeText" text-anchor="start" style="fill-opacity: 1;"></text>
          <text x="10" dy="1.5em" class="nodeText" text-anchor="start"></text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Nobody will help you here if you don't show your code (a [MCVE]).

Comment: updated my original comment

Answer (score 2):

i hope you understand the concept

first you draw svg with width: 1535 and hight :685
you want to make g element on middle of it

middle of it means half of width(1535/2) and half of height (685/2)
w:767.5 h:342.5

you draw g and transform it. good point but you must set transform to right place, that means on middle of svg to 742.5 and 342.5

so that means you need transform x,y) it more (25,0)

why you set it wrong

```
<g class="node" transform="translate(0,25)">
```

it must be

```
 <g class="node" transform="translate(25,0)">
```

this is little example

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>


  svg{
        border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
  }

}

</style>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <svg width="200" height="100" overflow-y="hidden" class="overlay">
    <g transform="translate(70,20)scale(1)">
        <g class="node" transform="translate(30,30)">
          <circle class="nodeCircle" r="10" style="fill: black"</circle>
          <text x="10" dy=".35em" class="nodeText" text-anchor="start" style="fill-opacity: 1;"></text>
          <text x="10" dy="1.5em" class="nodeText" text-anchor="start"></text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
  
    <svg width="200" height="100" overflow-y="hidden" class="overlay">
    <g transform="translate(100,50)scale(1)">
        <g class="node" transform="translate(0,0)">
          <circle class="nodeCircle" r="10" style="fill: black"</circle>
          <text x="10" dy=".35em" class="nodeText" text-anchor="start" style="fill-opacity: 1;"></text>
          <text x="10" dy="1.5em" class="nodeText" text-anchor="start"></text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
  
  <br/>
  
 <svg width="200" height="100" overflow-y="hidden" class="overlay">
    <g transform="translate(200,50)scale(1)">
        <g class="node" transform="translate(0,0)">
          <circle class="nodeCircle" r="10" style="fill: black"</circle>
          <text x="10" dy=".35em" class="nodeText" text-anchor="start" style="fill-opacity: 1;"></text>
          <text x="10" dy="1.5em" class="nodeText" text-anchor="start"></text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
  
   <svg width="200" height="100" overflow-y="hidden" class="overlay">
    <g transform="translate(100,10)scale(1)">
        <g class="node" transform="translate(100,40)">
          <circle class="nodeCircle" r="10" style="fill: black"</circle>
          <text x="10" dy=".35em" class="nodeText" text-anchor="start" style="fill-opacity: 1;"></text>
          <text x="10" dy="1.5em" class="nodeText" text-anchor="start"></text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
</body>
```